# How to find duplicate values in mysql table based on ANY y out of x columns where y<=x

Tags: mysql, sql

how to find duplicates on a table with three columns (col1,col2,col3) if ANY two of the columns have duplicate?

put in pseudo-query it would look like this:

If col1 and col2 are the same, then select

if col2 and col3 are the same, then select

if col1 and col3 are the same, then select

if col1,col2 and col3 are the same, then select

I don't want to use 'IF' because the number of columns are actually greater than 10 which would make the 'IF' query very tedious.

thanks.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If there's 10 columns you need to de-duplicate maybe you instead have a many to many (but distinct) relationship?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**N.B.** *I took your question to mean, that 2 **rows** are considered duplicates if two or more of their column values are equal. If you were just looking for duplicate values in **columns** for the same row, @GordonLinoff's answer is more appropriate*

In MySQL booleans are actually represented as 0 or 1

For your three column example, the condition

```
(a.col1 = b.col1) + (a.col2 = b.col2) + (a.col3 = b.col3) >= 2
```

should do the trick

For example, assuming you have a unique `id` column:

```
   SELECT *
     FROM your_table a 
    WHERE EXISTS (
     SELECT 1
       FROM your_table b
      WHERE (a.col1 = b.col1) + (a.col2 = b.col2) + (a.col3 = b.col3) >= 2 
        AND a.id != b.id /** Don't consider the same row */
          )
```

**UPDATE**

I'm not surprised that you get a large time difference between 1k and 130k. I imagine the scale will be linear so 15s * 130/1 = 1950s, which is about 30 minutes for querying on the full table.

Also don't forget that for each row, the query is checking all the other rows for duplicates. This is why just fetching the whole table is faster.

I would hope that you only need to use this query as a one-off to identify the dupes. If not, it would point to some iffy database design and likely the table could be refactored to better suit its purpose. This is the XY Problem that @apokryfos is referring to in his comment on your question.

The above query will not allow the use of any indexes on the columns, due to the complicated condition.

You could *potentially* reach a result faster by using `UNION ALL`, assuming you have an individual index on some of the columns and `id` is the PK of the table.

```
  SELECT base.*
    FROM your_table base
    JOIN (

    SELECT a.id, 1 col_match
      FROM your_table a
     WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
        FROM your_table b
       WHERE b.col1 = a.col1
         AND b.id != a.id
           )

     UNION ALL

    SELECT a.id, 1 col_match
      FROM your_table a
     WHERE EXISTS (
       SELECT 1
         FROM your_table b
        WHERE b.col2 = a.col2
          AND b.id != a.id
           )

     UNION ALL

    SELECT a.id, 1 col_match
      FROM your_table a
     WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
        FROM your_table b
       WHERE b.col3 = a.col3
         AND b.id != a.id
           )

         ) raw
      ON raw.id = base.id

GROUP BY base.id
  HAVING SUM(raw.col_match) >= 2
```

It may look hefty, but could easily be built dynamically in an application layer for your ten plus columns.

Bear in mind, if you have more duplicates than uniques, it may make sense to invert this logic.

Comment: You also need to mention that `a` and `b` are aliases to same table and need to use self join.

Comment: Can't this be more dynamic?

Comment: thank you. i tried but it looks like it's comparing itself therefore always true.

Comment: @KeZhao Ok, I'll elaborate! Sorry was in a rush waiting for an appointment!

Comment: @Cid Maybe, but it's tricky with MySQL and feels like over-engineering. If there is an application layer, you could declare an array and build the query from that

Comment: what does "select 1" mean here?

Comment: @KeZhao, When using EXISTS you're really just checking to see if there is a row.. so there's no need to SELECT any of the column values. SELECTing a constant like 1 is just as good and doesn't require the engine going into the row to get the values. Having said that, I believe the engine recognises this in the case of EXISTS and will ignore the SELECTed columns, so SELECT * is fine too. I tend to do SELECT 1 to get in the habit for when I need the same logic but NOT in an EXISTS statement and it can help with performance.

Comment: thanks. my table has 130k+ rows, so when i ran this query without limit, it takes forever to fetch the result. when i limit the result to 1000 rows, it took 15 seconds to fetch. I am a bit confused because fetching the entire table only took 3 seconds...

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best bet with MySQL is:

```
where col1 in (col2, col3, col4, . . . ) or
      col2 in (col3, col4, . . . ) or
      col3 in (col4, . . . ) or
      . . .
```

Comment: Wow, I may have totally misread the question! I answered a totally different question.. :P

Comment: @Arth . . . I think I understand.  I am interpreting the question as being about columns *in the same row*.  I do think that is what the OP intends.

Comment: Although having said that, you haven't quite got there, OP wants 2 or more matches, not 1 or more matches.. perhaps use the addition method from my answer?

Comment: thank you. I think Arth is correct. What i mean is that two rows have the same value in two or more columns, then select.

Comment: I was thinking about a way to solve it dynamically using a subquery or function with `SELECT c.COLUMN_NAME FROM myDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'myTable' WHERE c.COLUMN_NAME <> 'someColToExclude'` to compare some col against **n** number of cols

Comment: @Cid, well you could.. but it's unlikely that this will be done for more than one table, or even used regularly. While your solution would be reusable, it would be harder to read and debug, and I would definitely solve a problem like this individually first before refactoring to a generic solution.

Comment: @Arth I'm not skilled enough in SQL to manage to write a such query, I tried but I was unable to use it